# Rails 4: Access all CRUD from index.html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I'm trying to create only a 1 page index site. 
I Want to handle creating, deleting, editing all within my 1 index. (very basic)

However, I followed the beginners for getting started:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Example of my article controller:

```
def index
 @articles = Article.all #Create Articles and then add the for loop inside the index.html
 @article = Article.new
end

def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
  redirect_to @article
 end
end

def new
 @article = Article.new
end 
...

private
def article_params
 params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

I Use @articles to populate all articles ever added.  And then @article to for CRUD. Except I can't get full control to CRUD from the index.html page.

```
<form role="form" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form_for @article do |f| %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textUserInputDescription"><%= f.label :title %><br/><%= f.text_field :title %>
            </label>
            <label for="textUserInputDescription"><%= f.label :text %><br/><%= f.text_area :text %> </label>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><%= f.submit %></button>
          </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

When I click Submit, It does not add to my database.

My Question is: How do I get access to CRUD all from within the index.html?

Thanks for your time, I'm still learning Rails/CRUD/ActiveRecord and following tutorials.

Comment: I'm assuming `article_params` should be `params[:article]` ?

Comment: Made an edit, it's a private method def article_params (from the tutorial)

Comment: I'm making some progress. Trying a link_to with a post
<%= link_to "create", articles_path(:title => 'value1', :text => 'value2'), method: :post %>

Except now I'm being returned: 
param is missing or the value is empty: article

For
params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)

Not sure why my param is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed f.submit to:

```
<%= button_to "Create", new_article_path(@article[:title], @article[:text]), method: :post %>
```